# Using the same Django template for multiple views 

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Imagine you have a template which **has a button** that by clicking on it, you will will be **redirected** to another template to choose an item and then **come back to previous template**. Something like this scheme :

```
(Template 1)
|
|
|
*------------------ > (Template 2, with some items)
                      |
                      |
                      |
                (Select an Item)
                      |
                      |
<---------------------*
|
|    
(Template 1 , again)
```

But when I redirect to my previous template, it seems that I lost all of my items that I filled-in before. I just need to **override** one part in original template and not all of it.

Needless to say, I have **two view functions**: One that creates Template-1 and another one for passing the selected item to the original template !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't be directed to another template, you can only be directed to another view. (A template is pretty much irrelevant to the whole request/response cycle; it's just one of the ways that Django can produce a response, but isn't a necessary part of it and can even be used outside it, for example in sending emails.)

The way to preserve state between views is to use [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/sessions/).

Comment: +1 for pointing to template's independent nature  .. thanks for hint